# Is their any option to execute custom python or any lang. script(s) on newly created VM as part of ARM template execution immd. after VM gets created?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I can come up with an ARM Template which creates all required resources along with new VMs for my environment, But I need to execute script(s) on newly created VMs every time I create a new VM.
Can we run the Python/batch scripts immediately after VM gets installed as part of ARM Templates?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the recommended way to handle this would be to use the [Azure Custom Script Extension for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) or the [Azure Custom Script Extension for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux). You could provide all your post deployment tasks as part of the custom script.

This is what I'm using, and I put a sample command in.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        .....
        "virtualMachines_vm_name": {
            "defaultValue": "vm_name",
            "type": "String"
        },
        .....
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachines_vm_name')]",
            "location": "eastasia",
            "tags": {
                .....
            },
            "identity": {
                .....
            },
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "Standard_B2ms"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                .....
                },
                "osProfile": {
                .....
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                .....
                },
                "licenseType": "Windows_Server",
                "priority": "Regular"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_vm_name'), '/vmext-', parameters('virtualMachines_vm_name'))]",
            "location": "eastasia",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachines_vm_name'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "AssetName": "vm_name",
                "AssetRole": "application"
            },
            "properties": {
                "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": false,
                "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
                "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
                "settings": {
                    "fileUris": ["https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myscript.ps1"],
                    "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File myscript.ps1"
                },
                "protectedSettings": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Check [this](https://octopus.com/blog/azure-script-extension) link for more info about how you can configure the script. Store your script in a storage account and follow the instructions.

This block is what you should be looking at:

`"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",`

Hopefully the sample above can get you going!

Comment: Can I have an example ARM template where creating a new Windows VM and running a sample script on newly created VM.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect a template that highlights the extension part, the rest I've mostly omitted cause it's the same. Only included the other objects so you can make sense of where to place the extension.

Comment: Hey just checking if you had a chance to try it? If it satisfies you or answers your question, please vote up or mark as answer. Doing this helps us and the community too! Thanks again